# Toolbar button that injects HTML in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, com-interop

I'm building a browser extension for Internet Explorer. The goal is to have the user be able to click a toolbar button and inject html on any site the user might be visiting at the moment.

My class is implementing IOleCommandTarget and IObjectWithSite and I have managed to get the toolbar button showing by adding some info to the registry, however I just cannot get access to the html document so that I can manipulate it. Some debugging have shown that I first end up in the IObjectWithSite.SetSite method and then the IOleCommandTarget.Exec method.  If I implement the solution as a BHO I can subscribe to the webbrowser events in the SetSite method but when I try to do the same thing in the Exec method the cast to WebBrowser fails. How do I build this very small and simple extension?

Comment: You are correct that SetSite() will be called first.  You should be able to query your site for the same browser objects that your BHO does.  Can you post (the minimum amount of) your code for your SetSite() implementation, and indicate where it fails?

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar.h

```
CComQIPtr<IWebBrowser2, &IID_IWebBrowser2> m_spWebBrowser2;
```

Toolbar.cpp

```
STDMETHODIMP Toolbar::SetSite(IUnknown *pUnkSite)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CComQIPtr<IServiceProvider> sp = pUnkSite;
    if(!m_spWebBrowser2 && sp)
    {
        //BHO immediately eotjiman ToolBar does not get it to the Obtained through QueryService.
        sp->QueryService(IID_IWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&m_spWebBrowser2);
    }
    else
    {
        m_spWebBrowser2.Release();
        return E_POINTER;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I hope it helps :)